# Grails Cache Plugin: Cacheable key using only two of three params

Tags: grails, groovy, ehcache

With a restful api call such as

```
myserver/api/mydata?req?%7Bcode%3A%2244%22%2C%20name%3A%22sally%22%2C%20version%3A7%7D
```

where the parameters passed in are code=44, name=sally, and version=7, and I want to cache the response using only name and version as keys -- but not code.

What I want to do is this:

```
 @Cacheable(value="myCache", key="#name.concat(#version)")
 def mydata() {

 .....

 }
```

But #name and #version both resolve to null.  Apparently that format only works for method parameters, not params.name or params.version.

If I leave the key as default, the cache uses all three params as the key (if I change one, the cache is not used).  That would be great except I want the cache to be used regardless of 'code' and based on 'name' and 'version' as keys.

My guess is that I will need to override the default KeyGenerator, but I have tried and failed.  Any advice on how to do this?

Or is there a way to access the params properties with the @Cacheable annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil,
The simplest solution would be to define the name and version as parameters of the controller action:

```
@Cacheable(value="myCache", key="#name.concat(#version)")
def mydata(String name, String version) {
}
```

If the name and version parameters are not always provided simply add a default value in the method signature:

```
@Cacheable(value="myCache", key="#name.concat(#version)")
def mydata(String name = null, String version = 0) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ruben, that would be an awesome easy solution -- if it worked for me.  'key="#name"' gives me the "maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?" error.  So I try, 'key="#p0"', and get the same thing.  Maybe there is something else I am missing?

Comment: BTW, when I try to set the default values, I get: "Parameter [name] to method [myData] has default value [Peter].  Default parameter values are not allowed in controller action methods."  Could that be a clue?

Comment: Phil, here is how I am handling a custom construction of a cache key in a Grails service: @Cacheable(value="senders", key="'SDT' + #senderId")
Set<SenderDocumentType> getSenderDocumentTypes(String senderId)

Comment: Yeah, so when you call getSenderDocumentTypes you pass in a senderId, right?  My method is called via restful api and nothing is passed in that fashion; it gets the parameters from the params property.  I know @Cacheable can see params because it uses them if the default key is not overridden.  The problem is that I cannot access params in the annotation itself to pull out only the values I want to use.

Comment: But you can now also declare parameters you expect as the method parameters in a controller. If the params object contains key-value pairs with the same key as the name of the method parameter it simply uses that one. So the behaviour should not be different with the method parameters or whithout them.

Comment: I have tried that in every conceivable way to no avail --  method parameters are always null.  When you say "now", could it be a version issue?  I am running Grails 2.1.1, Servlet api 2.5, Tomcat 6, and Java 1.6.

Comment: It should be working with Grails 2+, and I am working with Grails 2.1.1 . And the params contains the name and version keys?

Comment: Phil, when I use the parameter part of the URL you provided I get the following params content: ['req?{code:"44", name:"sally"', version:7}=:'']. So it is normal that name and version remain null. And this probably is also the reason why your cache key generation is not working!

Comment: Yep, I think the problem is that the client is sending the parameters as a JSON.  I can't find anyway to parse that JSON into the cache key.  I tried using a wrapper method to parse the params and then call another method that would be cacheable, but "self-invocation" ignores the annotation, even if that method is in another class.  I guess I have given up.  Thanks for the help.  I will accept your answer as it will work for everyone else.

Comment: You could have the incoming requests with JSON payload go to a separate API controller, and have that controller redirect to your current controller with the params extracted from the JSON payload. If it is only data you are caching, and not a GSP response, it would be better to extract the data lookup to a Grails service and cache those results. The controller would than be responsible for parsing the request, and invoking the Grails service.

Comment: Yes!  Instead of calling the second method, I redirected to it and thus @Cacheable isn't ignored.  It works!  Amazing that no where on the web does anyone mention this solution -- they all recommend aspectJ weaving, etc, which is a major headache.  Thank you, Ruben! (You're not looking for a job, are you?)

Comment: No, not looking for job. Glad I could help with your problem.